# cannot parse json req.body using node/express

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm new to node and express, and writing my first app. I have a json parsing issue that I've been struggling with for hours:

my code looks something like this:

```
...
var app = express()
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded() ); 
....

app.post('/callback', function(req, res, next) {
         var body = req.body
         var subscriptionId = body['subscriptionId']

         res.send() // 204
         console.dir(body);
         console.log(subscriptionId);
...
         })
```

All my efforts to parse the subscriptionID out of the JSON request is unsuccessful. FYI, below is the console dump from the request. The subscriptionID comes as undefined.

[ { collectionType: 'activities',
    date: '2014-07-05',
    ownerId: '296XYK',
    ownerType: 'user',
    subscriptionId: 'E3636aaa4-8482-40B7-9533-B805F002416A' } ]
undefined

What am I doing wrong? Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

The object is wrapped in an array.  Try:

```
body[0]['subscriptionId']
```